# Query posts using dropdown menu of custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have created [this](http://www.wearesalt.org/category/horizontal-list/) category archive which contains a table of 100 posts. The table contains 3 custom fields (Gender,Continent,Sector) and there is also a fourth ('Overall' with the only value 'All') which is not inside the table and their values for each post are inside the table cells of every entry/post. 
I have placed above the table four select tags (the four drop down menus) which I would like to filter the posts depending on which option of a certain select tag is chosen. To be more specific when a user choses for example select tag 'Continent' and option 'Europe' I would to query all posts with custom field value 'Europe'. Is it possible to do that by using an if statement and how exactly would I syntax that? The select tags are the following:

For custom field Overall

```
<select>
<option value="all">All</option>
</select>
```

For custom field Gender

```
<select>
<option value="gender">Select Gender</option>
<option value="male" >Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

For custom field Continent

```
<select>                    
<option value="continent">Select Continent</option>
<option value="europe">Europe</option>
<option value="america">America</option>
<option value="africa">Africa</option>
<option value="asia">Asia</option></select>
```

For custom field Sector

```
<select> 
<option value="sector">Select Sector</option>
<option value="retail">FMCG/Retail</option>
<option value="various">Various</option>
<option value="finance">Finance</option>
<option value="se">SE</option>
<option value="energy">Energy</option>
<option value="education">Education</option>
<option value="fb">F&B</option>
<option value="environment">Environment </option>
<option value="telco">Tech/telco </option>
<option value="fashion">Fashion </option>
<option value="media">Media </option>
<option value="construction">Construction </option>
<option value="health">Health </option>
<option value="tech">Tech </option>
<option value="industry">Industry </option>
</select>
```

Comment: What i think, It can be done through AJAX. Means, when user click on europe, all POSTs regarding europe come and when user click ALL, all post should come. Is it ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want but because I am not so experienced in this I do not know how to put it in code.

Comment: Ok.. wait for 5 min.

Comment: You can use query post by meta key and meta value https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query  , https://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_posts-where-custom-field-is-true . Try this sample code

Comment: Try also this one http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html

Comment: Yes but how do I connect the queries with the select tag and the options ?

Comment: Using Form POST you can pass select tag values to queries             <form id="brandsearch" method="post" action="">
<select name="brand" id="brand">
<option value="">All</option>                                                                  <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</form>                                                                                                     <?php   if (!empty($_POST['brand'])) :
//Do your queries here
    endif; ?>

Comment: I will try that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to query post by meta key and value

```
<form name="res" action="" method="post">
<select name="gender">
<option value="gender">Select Gender</option>
<option value="male" >Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) :
$result = query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'your post type name',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'gender',
            'value' => 'male',          
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'continent',
            'value' => 'USA',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'all',
            'value' => 'all',
        )
    )
) );

print_r($result);

?>
```